# JavaScript augment an imported namespace

Tags: javascript

I would like to augment an existing namespace by mixing in my own functions. Something like:

```
// namespaceWithMixins.js
import * as N from "namespace"

const fun1 = (x, y) => x + y
const fun2 = (x, y) => x * y

export {...N, fun1, fun2}
```

So that elsewhere I can do:

```
import * as N from "namespaceWithMixins.js"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use any of the members from `N`, then you could just directly re-export it.

```js
export * from "namespace"

const fun1 = (x, y) => x + y
const fun2 = (x, y) => x * y
```